# How to call a function on page load in jdeveloper fusion middleware application?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am logging in user programmatically in oracle fusion middleware application.
I want to call a function on page load to check user session.
How can i call bean function on page load programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you need to call function in event type pre-render view.

```
<f:metadata>
        <?audit suppress oracle.ide.xml.validation-error?>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{your-function-here}"/>
    </f:metadata>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on why you want to call a method on page load. If it's something you want to do on entry to a page - as you navigate from another page to this page - then the best practice is to put the method call on the Task Flow containing the  page, not embedded in the page source itself.

On the Task Flow, add a Method Call component as part of the navigation.  Benefits are you make the method call part of the structure of the application as documented in the Task Flow, so it is easy for others to see and it's easier to change than having to modify the page source.